# How to add new attributes to existing simple products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, simple-product

I added some products as simple products. Later on i created certain attributes. Is there anyway to make these attributes applicable to the products i added before creating the attributes. I checked out certain links and found ways to do it for configurable products but nothing about simple products.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, possible

1. First check what `attribute set` you are using in simple products.
2. Now go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute sets`
3. `Drag n drop` your new attributes to same attribute sets.
4. Now go to `Catalog->Manage product` Your anew attribute should be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you assigned any product attribute to any attribute set, that attribute will be available for all products of that attribute set. It does not depend on product created date.

You just have to set that attribute value inside that product from

```
Catalog -> Manage Product
```